# Перевод из шестнадцатиричного в десятичный

Tags: c++

Подскажите пожалуйста как перевести из шестнадцатиричного в десятичный вид числа. Язык C++

Comment: https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://dsl.msk.ru/pdf/dmx512/bin_hex.pdf =)

Comment: Авторской мысли не хватает... Могу подсказать: переводите каждую 16-чную цифру в 2-ичную (там будет блок из 4-х нулей и единиц), затем -- из двоичной в нашу родную. Полагаю, это не трудно...

Answer (score 2):

*В `C++` это правильно делается следующим образом:*

```
const std::string hex("0x31c3");
std::istringstream stream(hex);

int dec;
stream >> std::hex >> dec;
```

Answer (score 1):

Если нет специальных требований, например, неограниченная входная строка на входе и на выходе, то вполне можно использовать функцию strtol из stdlib.h. Тогда

```
char *input = "dead";
char *next;
long int value = strtol(input, &next, 16);
```

Comment: Еще годится scanf (sscanf) со спецификатором типа %x

Comment: Вообще странный вопрос, а в какой системе счисления автор вопроса обычно выводит ? 
Возможно он **не знает** о существовании sprintf() ?

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант

```
//num - Число в 16-ричном формате
    int Numeral(const char*num){

        return static_cast<const int>(strtol(num, NULL, 16));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int i;
cin >> hex >> i;
cout << dec << i << endl;
return 0;
}
```